# Picklist issues inside global modal

Tags: lightning-experience, modal

I was rendering global modal using **lightning:overlayLibrary** tag which will display the fields using `lightning:recordEditForm` and `lightning:inputField`. If i added the any picklists at the end of the body, options are showing inside the body footer(options hiding behind the footer).[image]

If we open any standard modal which is also showing global modal, if any picklists are at the bottom of the body, the options panel itself is adjusting according to the picklist position. [image]

How to replicate the same styling available in the standard modal to custom global modal?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like salesforce did fixed the issue when picklist is present inside the global modal, drop down height is adjusted according to the modal height and picklist options.

Comment: Did you add any styles to fix this issue?

Comment: No, I didn't @sdandamud1

Comment: Issues is fixed or still exist?

Comment: Its fixed @sdandamud1

Comment: I still have issue, tried multiple ways but no luck

Comment: Are you using custom modal or standard modal(with lightning:overlayLibrary)?

Comment: Yes custom modal